# set mock return value for any integer input parameter

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

```
when(candidateService.findById(1)).thenReturn(new Candidate());
```

I want to extend this behaviour for any Integer(not necessarily for 1)

If I wrire

```
when(candidateService.findById( any(Integer.class)  )).thenReturn(new Candidate());
```

I have compilation error

> The method findById(Integer) in the type CandidateService is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Matcher)

**UPDATE**

imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
```

Comment: Which `any` method did you statically import?  The Mockito one or the Hamcrest one?  It needs to be the Mockito one.  If you've used `org.hamcrest.Matchers.any`, then change it to `org.mockito.Matchers.any`.

Comment: <Object> Object org.mockito.Matchers.any()

I use

Comment: Really?  Because the code that you've posted works perfectly well for me.  Are you able to post the whole class, including the import statements?

Comment: I am added info to topic

Comment: I actually meant that you should post the whole class, so I could see what the error was.  But never mind.  There is no import here for `any`, so it looks like you're NOT actually using the Mockito one.  Have you defined `any` somewhere else?  If so, that is the problem.

Comment: today it works. I don't understand what happened yesterday

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I know exactly what happened.  You would have been importing `org.hamcrest.Matchers.any`.  It's the only explanation that fits what you described.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try anyInt():

```
when(candidateService.findById(anyInt())).thenReturn(new Candidate());
```

For example I have anyLong() in my project:

```
when(dao.getAddress(anyLong())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(dto));
```

EDIT:
You must import:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
```

Comment: You saved my day! Not sure why but `Mockito.any<Int>()` causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.any<Int>() must not be null`. At the same time `Mockito.anyInt()` doesn't throw any exceptions.